# Há alguma maneira de remover todas os sysout de um Projeto?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou montando um WebService e tem alguns *sysout* de teste de imprimir as variáveis, e como há em vários arquivos diferentes, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de remover todos os *sysout* do projeto no **Eclipse Oxygen** de uma vez só.

Comment: Se for o atalho pra chamar o método `System.out.println` creio que você desativa nas preferencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felipe o mais próximo de optimizar esse processo é você utilizar a função localizar e substituir do seu editor de texto.

alguns editores tem função de buscar o texto `sysout` ou `System.out.println` em vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo, e você pode substitui-los por um texto em branco. Fazendo assim a remoção de todos.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos fazer uma classe para isso:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public final class Silencio {

    public static final OutputStream OUTPUT_STREAM_SILENCIO = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) {
            // Não faz nada.
        }
    };

    public static final PrintStream PRINT_STREAM_SILENCIO =
            new PrintStream(OUTPUT_STREAM_SILENCIO);

    private Silencio() {}

    public static void silenciar(Runnable r) {
        PrintStream outOriginal = System.out;
        PrintStream errOriginal = System.err;
        try {
            System.setOut(PRINT_STREAM_SILENCIO);
            System.setErr(PRINT_STREAM_SILENCIO);
            r.run();
        } finally {
            System.setOut(outOriginal);
            System.setErr(errOriginal);
        }
    }
}
```

Há dois objetos aí que são um `OutputStream` que descarta toda a saída e um `PrintStream` feito com esse `OutputStream`. O método `silenciar(Runnable)` é o método malandro que cala a boca do `System.out` e o `System.err` para executar um `Runnable` e restaura o original em seguida.

Eis um teste:

```
public class TesteSilencio {

    private static int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Será que vai ter barulho?");
        Silencio.silenciar(() -> {
            System.out.println("Bla bla bla");
            System.err.println("Gwa gwa gwa");
            System.out.println("Bla bla bla");
            System.err.println("Gwa gwa gwa");
            x++;
        });
        System.out.println("Será que o System.out ainda funciona? Vamos tentar de novo!");
        Silencio.silenciar(TesteSilencio::metodoBarulhento);
        System.out.println("Silêncio?");
        System.out.println("Resultado: " + x);
    }

    public static void metodoBarulhento() {
        System.out.println("Bla bla bla");
        System.err.println("Gwa gwa gwa");
        System.out.println("Bla bla bla");
        System.err.println("Gwa gwa gwa");
        x++;
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Será que vai ter barulho?
Será que o System.out ainda funciona? Vamos tentar de novo!
Silêncio?
Resultado: 2
```

O fato de haver um `Resultado: 2` também evidencia que o código silenciado foi de fato executado, mas sem que a saída do `System.out` ou `System.err` fosse poluída por eles.

Comment: Pelo que entendi nesse código, não é exatamente o que eu queria, ele está apenas silenciando. Queria deixar o código mais limpo, removendo os system.out de forma rapida

Comment: Pensei que você tivesse permissão de escrita nas variáveis `System.out` e `System.err`. Ou o `setter` também prevê outras malandragens?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Estou usando os métodos [`setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) e [`setErr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-) para fazer isso. Obviamente que se houver um `SecurityManager` que não conceda permissão para tal, o resultado será uma `SecurityException`.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Se a ideia é fazer `System.out = PRINT_STREAM_SILENCIO`, isso não compila porque o `out` e o `err` estão com o modificador `final`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não tinha percebido esse detalhe. Ia me deparar com um erro de compilação e não iria saber contorná-lo.

Comment: Ainda não entendi muito bem o código, ele apenas silencia os print ?